# route priority regular expression in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes, laravel-5.3

I have made two routes:

Single tour route:

```
Route::get('{category}/{slug}',
      ['as' => 'single.tour',
       'uses' => 'PublicController@singleTour'])
        ->where('category', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+')
        ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
```

Travel guide route:

```
Route::get('{pcategory}/{slug}',
      ['as' => 'travel-guide',
       'uses' => 'PublicController@getTravelguide'])
        ->where('pcategory', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+')
        ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
```

both with `Regular Expression Constraints` but still the second route `travel-guide` is being redirected to view of first route `single.tour`. I tried replacing `{travel-guide}` with `travel-guide` [static] but still getting same problem. Though I found solution [worst idea] the solution by attaching any extensions like `(php,html,jsp,aspx,css....etc)` to the url example below:

```
Route::get('{pcategory}/{slug}.php',
      ['as' => 'travel-guide',
       'uses' => 'PublicController@getTravelguide'])
        ->where('pcategory', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+')
        ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
```

It works well returning its own view. But this is not the best solution. Can anyone suggest me solution to this problem ?

Comment: highest route declaration in file = 1st match = returning that one

Comment: Suggestion for solution please ?

Comment: suggestion is to make a better distinction between the routes, not based on a regular expression like this

Comment: A demo please using my scenario .

Comment: `Route::get('{'singleOrTravel'}/{category}/{slug}',` for example